# is there any way to find out the installation path of a program on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I installed the nosql database Mongodb before on my ubuntu before. now I forget the installation path of it, does anybody know the trick or method to find out the installation path of a program on ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I would just do

```
sudo updatedb
```

then

```
locate -i mongodb
```

on ubuntu the installation path will probably be somewhere in the /usr/share path.

Answer (score 2):

To find the path of the application, you can use the which command, followed by the executable that you would have run.

```
which <commandname>
```

In here something like

```
which mongodb
```

I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try `man which`.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain a way to use `which` in this case?